# Check for duplicated values in the internal table

Tags: abap, internal-tables

How can I check the repetitive value in the "Form #" column?

[image]

I want to highlight it later as duplicate record.

```
  LOOP AT ZVBELNEXTTAB WHERE werks IN werks.

ZVBELNEXTTAB_COPY-WERKS        = ZVBELNEXTTAB-WERKS.
ZVBELNEXTTAB_COPY-MANDT        = ZVBELNEXTTAB-MANDT.
ZVBELNEXTTAB_COPY-BUKRS        = ZVBELNEXTTAB-BUKRS.
ZVBELNEXTTAB_COPY-VBELN        = ZVBELNEXTTAB-VBELN.
ZVBELNEXTTAB_COPY-EVBELN       = ZVBELNEXTTAB-EVBELN.
ZVBELNEXTTAB_COPY-FKDAT        = ZVBELNEXTTAB-FKDAT.
ZVBELNEXTTAB_COPY-VBLSTAT      = ZVBELNEXTTAB-VBLSTAT.
ZVBELNEXTTAB_COPY-ZPRN         = ZVBELNEXTTAB-ZPRN.
ZVBELNEXTTAB_COPY-UNAME        = ZVBELNEXTTAB-UNAME.
ZVBELNEXTTAB_COPY-TYPE         = ZVBELNEXTTAB-TYPE.



curr = ZVBELNEXTTAB-EVBELN.
lv_tab = SY-TABIX + 1.
READ TABLE ZVBELNEXTTAB INDEX lv_tab.
next = ZVBELNEXTTAB-EVBELN.

IF curr GT next.
  a = curr - next.
ELSE.
  a = next - curr.
ENDIF.

IF a GT 1.
  curr = curr + 1.
  next = next - 1.

  ZVBELNEXTTAB_COPY-MISSINGFROM   = curr.
  ZVBELNEXTTAB_COPY-MISSINGTO     = next.
ELSE.
  ZVBELNEXTTAB_COPY-MISSINGFROM   = ''.
  ZVBELNEXTTAB_COPY-MISSINGTO     = ''.
ENDIF.



APPEND ZVBELNEXTTAB_COPY.
SORT ZVBELNEXTTAB_COPY BY EVBELN.


ENDLOOP.

ENDFORM.
```

I still trying to check the duplicate "Form #" column by using 1 dimensional array by looping them.

Answer (score 1):

Use [GROUP BY](https://help.sap.com/http.svc/rc/abapdocu_752_index_htm/7.52/en-US/abaploop_at_itab_group_by.htm) functionality during looping. You wanna extract duplicates based on comparison fields **Company code, Plant, Form #, Sales Doc, Billing date, Username**.

So you should write something like this:

```
TYPES tt_vbeln TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF vbeln WITH DEFAULT KEY. 

DATA duplicates TYPE tt_vbeln. 
LOOP AT ZVBELNEXTTAB INTO DATA(zvbeln) 
GROUP BY ( BUKRS = zvbeln-BUKRS
           WERKS = zvbeln-WERKS
           VBELN = zvbeln-VBELN
           EVBELN = zvbeln-EVBELN
           FKDAT = zvbeln-FKDAT
           UNAME = zvbeln-UNAME
           size = GROUP SIZE ) 
ASCENDING REFERENCE INTO DATA(group_ref). 

CHECK group_ref->*-size > 1. "extracting dups
duplicates = VALUE tt_vbeln( BASE duplicates FOR <form_num> IN GROUP group_ref ( <form_num> ) ). 
* setting color 
MODIFY duplicates FROM VALUE tt_vbeln( line_color = 'C410' ) TRANSPORTING line_color WHERE line_color IS INITIAL. 
ENDLOOP.
```

That allows you to extract sets of duplicated values like this

[image]

By the way, in the above sample rows of blue dataset differ in fields **Form #** and **Username**, so my GROUP snippet won't actually work on them. You should adjust grouping fields accordingly, for example leave only VBELN field as grouping field.

Beforehand you should add field `line_color` to your structure where you will put color codes for duplicates datasets.

Good sample of conditional coloring an ALV [resides here](https://www.erpgreat.com/abap/line-color-in-alv-example.htm).

Comment: where should i put this line of process inside the form itself?

Comment: You can make separate button for ALV coloring and refresh the grid in-place, or execute this stuff before first display of grid or before each display